# Convert date format: Fri, 9 Aug 2053 00:00:00 GMT

Tags: python, datetime

I'm attempting to convert the string date `Fri, 9 Aug 2053 00:00:00 GMT` to day/month/year: `9/8/2053`

How do I exclude the `Fri` and `GMT` part from the string without using a string replace? Can this be accomplished using the datetime api ?

Here is my attempt, but I am unsure how to achieve the above:

```
a = 'Fri, 9 Aug 2053 00:00:00 GMT'
b = '9/8/2053'

from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.strptime(a, '%d %m %Y')  
print(dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this,

```
from datetime import datetime

a = 'Fri, 9 Aug 2053 00:00:00 GMT'
dt = datetime.strptime(a, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')

print(dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```

Output :

```
09/08/2053
```

Answer (score 5):

As all the above solutions, with the difference that you can use the `#` sign in order to remove any zero padding in day or month:

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.strptime(a, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
print(dt.strftime("%#d/%#m/%Y"))
```

Output:

```
9/8/2053
```

This works for Windows. For Unix systems, consult using the `-` sign.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
>>> dt = datetime.strptime(a, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')  
>>> print(dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
'09/08/2053'
```

You can find a reference of the different `strftime` directives [here](http://strftime.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `%Z` for the `GMT` as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime

a = 'Fri, 9 Aug 2053 00:00:00 GMT'
dt = datetime.strptime(a, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')  
print(dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```